# Cannot fetch secrets from key vault using user assigned managed identity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azureportal, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to fetch secrets from azure key vault using user assigned managed identity, but I am getting an error when I deploy my code in Azure and test. When I test it in local in my Visual Studio, it works fine.

**Exception:**

One or more errors occurred. (ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Content:

Headers:
Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2023 13:05:11 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-CORRELATION-ID: REDACTED
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Below is the azure configurations:

[image: ManagedIdentity]

[image: KeyVaultConfig]

[image: AzureRoleAssignment]

Below is the code I am using in startup.cs file to set the managed identity client id

```
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "123456-abcde" }));
```

Please assist.

Comment: Please go through the [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad) it might help you

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found an answer for this question. I have added `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` key in function app configurations and it started to work.

Comment: It's works by adding AZURE_CLIENT_ID. Thanks